# Manually adding entries into app.config for Oracle Stored proc for entity framework application

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, stored-procedures, app-config

My Oracle proc looks as follows:

```
PROCEDURE "GET_SUPPLIERS" (
    SUPP_LIST OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS
BEGIN 

    OPEN SUPP_LIST FOR 
    SELECT 
        SUPPLIER_NAME 
    FROM 
        A_SUPPLIER  ;

END;
```

To get the resultset into my .net Entity framework application, I would have to manually enter the following setting 
into the app.config of Entity Framework project

```
  <oracle.dataaccess.client>
    <settings>
      <add name="SYSADM.GET_SUPPLIERS.RefCursor.SUPP_LIST" value="implicitRefCursor bindinfo='mode=Output'" />


      <add name="SYSADM.GET_SUPPLIERS.RefCursorMetaData.SUPP_LIST.Column.0"
           value="implicitRefCursor metadata='ColumnName=SUPPLIER_NAME;
           BaseColumnName=SUPPLIER_NAME;BaseSchemaName=SYSADM;BaseTableName=A_SUPPLIER;
           NativeDataType=varchar2;ProviderType=Varchar2;
           ProviderDBType=String;DataType=System.String;
           ColumnSize=10;AllowDBNull=true'" />


    </settings>
  </oracle.dataaccess.client>
```

Is there a more automated way of doing this with out manually adding these type of entries per column?

What if my stored proc returns 20 columns would I have to manually add 20 entries in the app.config?

Please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The question is a bit old, but nevertheless, someone might benefit from the answer.

In Visual Studio, go: 
`Server Explorer`->*Your connection*->*Your package/procedure*->*right mouse button*->`Run`

There you can check the `Select For Config` checkbox and click the 'Show Config' or 'Add Config to Project` to see and add the configuration to the App.Config file.

Comment: It sure did help! Oracle, as usual, has the weirdest way to do things. Robotron, one question though - how did you find it? Don't tell me "by experiment". There is got to be documentation somewhere?

Comment: To tell you the truth, I can't remember where I found it. It wasn't by experimenting, I know I saw it somewhere. It took me quite a while to find it, I remember that. Sorry I couldn't be more precise.

Comment: It is important to mention that Robotron's answer requires ODAC 12!

Answer (score 1):

I coudnt add a comment to Robotron answer ( i must have 50 reputation XD)
so here is the link of oracle documentation :
http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/12c/r1/appdev/dotnet/EntityFrameworkOBE/EntityFrameworkOBE.html#section1